# MySQL merge data from related tables and export as .csv

Tags: mysql, csv

I don't know MySQL very well so I need a bit of help with this task.. I hope it's ok to ask.

I have a table that i need to export which i did using the following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM `members`
WHERE `active` =1
AND `level` = 'full'
LIMIT 0 , 30000
```

This works perfect and gives me most of what I need including a user ID in the collumn called `id` but I also need to grab the related image for each member and add it to my exported .csv.

The images (filename) are stored in a different table called `images` but this only contains `galleryid`, `filename` and `defaultimg` (note I am only interested in data where `defaultimg = 1`)

The issue here is there is NO reference to the member (`id`) in this table.

For that I have to reference a different table called: `imagelinks` which contains 2 columns:

1) `id` which relates to my `galleryid` from the `images` table.

and

2) `memberid` which relates to the user ID `id` from the `members` table.

What a disaster of a setup I know.

So.. what I need to do and can't for the life of me work out is export a .csv with ALL the user data from the `members` table (as stated in my code above) with the addition of the `filename` data from the `images` table that coresponds to the referenced user (where `defaultimg = 1`).

Lastly, I also need to prepend a URL to the front of the `filename` data.

eg: The table has `my-image.jpg` but in the exported .csv I need it to be `http://www.domain.com/images/my-image.jpg`

I'm trying to do all of this in PhpMyAdmin.

Any help with this will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My syntax might be a bit off but this should be close...

SELECT members.*, CONCAT('http://www.domain.com/images/', images.filename) AS thefilename FROM members INNER JOIN imagelinks ON members.id=imagelinks.memberid INNER JOIN images ON images.galleryid=imagelinks.id WHERE members.active=1 AND members.level='full' AND images.defaultimg=1

Comment: Thanks @Bill I have the collumn at the end called thefilename which is great but it contained IDs not the URL with filename.. any ideas?

Comment: The ID is the `id` from `imagelinks`

Comment: the issue seems to be in this line: `SELECT members . * , 'http://www.domain.com/images/' + images.filename AS thefilename` as when I do this: `SELECT members . * , images.filename AS thefilename` I get the filename. Any ideas?

Comment: I had the concatenation wrong. I did a test on a PHPMyAdmin just now and I think my edited answer should work.